# How to assign values to the class attributes in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm new to C# programming and trying to write the following program using "Vihicle" interface properties that are inherited in 'Car', 'Truck'  classes. The problem I'm facing is this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred"

I get this while assigning the values to the Car properties. Here is my code:

```
namespace Inheritance_Assignment_2
{
    interface Vihicle
    {
        string Make
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        String Model
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        int Year
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        void DisplayInfo();
        float calculateMileage();
    }
    class Car : Vihicle
    {
        private string make;
        public string Make  // read-write instance property
        {
            get
            {
                return Make;
            }
            set
            {
                Make = value;
            }
        }
        private string model;
        public string Model  // read-write instance property
        {
            get
            {
                return Model;
            }
            set
            {
                Model = value;
            }
        }
        private int year;
        public int Year  // read-write instance property
        {
            get
            {
                return Year;
            }
            set
            {
                Year = value;
            }
        }
        public void DisplayInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Make);
            Console.WriteLine(Model);
            Console.WriteLine(Year);

        }
        public float calculateMileage()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            float value = random.Next(10, 20);
            return value;
        }
    }
    class Truck : Vihicle
    {
        private string make;
        public string Make  // read-write instance property
        {
            get
            {
                return Make;
            }
            set
            {
                Make = value;
            }
        }
        private string model;
        public string Model  // read-write instance property
        {
            get
            {
                return Model;
            }
            set
            {
                Model = value;
            }
        }
        private int year;
        public int Year  // read-write instance property
        {
            get
            {
                return Year;
            }
            set
            {
                Year = value;
            }
        }
        public void DisplayInfo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Make);
            Console.WriteLine(Model);
            Console.WriteLine(Year);

        }

        public float calculateMileage()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    class TowingTruck : Truck
    {
        public string TowingCapacity  // read-write instance property
        {
            get
            {
                return TowingCapacity;
            }
            set
            {
                TowingCapacity = value;
            }
        }
        public void DisplayInfo()    // Overrided function of class truck because this function doing some extra printing of
        {                           //TowingCapacity that is present in this TowingTruck Child of Truck Class
            Console.WriteLine(Make);
            Console.WriteLine(Model);
            Console.WriteLine(Year);
            Console.WriteLine(TowingCapacity);

        }

        public float calculateMileage()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    class DeliveryTruck : Truck
    {
      public string Make  // read-write instance property
        {
            get
            {
                return Make;
            }
            set
            {
                Make = value;
            }
        }
        public string Model  // read-write instance property
        {
            get
            {
                return Model;
            }
            set
            {
                Model = value;
            }
        }
        public int Year  // read-write instance property
        {
            get
            {
                return Year;
            }
            set
            {
                Year = value;
            }
        }
        /*
        public void DisplayInfo()
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Make);
            Console.WriteLine(Model);
            Console.WriteLine(Year);

        }

        public float calculateMileage()
        {
         //   throw new NotImplementedException();
            return 0;
        }
     */
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //while (true) // Loop indefinitely
            //{
            //    string name;
            //    int age;
            //    double height;

            //    Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
            //    name = Console.ReadLine();
            //    Console.Write("Enter your age: ");
            //    age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            //    Console.Write("Enter your height: ");
            //    height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            //    //Print a blank line
            //    Console.WriteLine();

            //    //Show the details you typed
            //    Console.WriteLine( name);
            //    Console.WriteLine( age);
            //    Console.WriteLine("Height is ", height);
            //    Console.WriteLine('\n');

            //}
            Car C = new Car();
            float rnum = C.calculateMileage();
            Console.WriteLine("Here is the Milage : " + rnum);
            C.Make = System.Console.ReadLine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("The employee information:");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Employee name: {0}", C.Make);

            //Console.Write("Enter your Model : ");
            //C.Model = Console.ReadLine();
            //Console.WriteLine(C.Model);
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at your properties:

```
private string make;
public string Make  // read-write instance property
{
    get
    {
        return Make;
    }
    set
    {
        Make = value;
    }
}
```

When you read a value from `Make`, it internally reads a value from `Make` (same with writing a value), which results in an infinite recursion.  You need to read/write from the variable which holds the value:

```
private string make;
public string Make  // read-write instance property
{
    get
    {
        return make;
    }
    set
    {
        make = value;
    }
}
```

A property's internal logic can't reference *itself*.  Something actually has to store the value.

**Edit:** Unless there's any particular reason to use properties like this (such as requiring more logic in the getters/setters), you can just use auto-generated properties to simplify the code.  So instead of this:

```
private string make;
public string Make  // read-write instance property
{
    get
    {
        return make;
    }
    set
    {
        make = value;
    }
}
```

You can just use this:

```
public string Make { get; set; }
```

The compiler automatically converts the latter into something very similar to the former (maybe with just a different backing variable name).

Comment: Thanks for help
one more thing should i add the interface Vihicle properties to  the Truck class and his child class TowingTruck too???
as the heirarchy is like

class Truck inherits interface vihicle
class TowingTruck inherits Truck

Thanks in advance

Comment: @HasanBadshah: When inheriting a class you don't need to re-implement inherited members, no.  `Truck` needs to implement members of an interface, but anything which inherits from `Truck` already gets that implementation from `Truck` itself.